# Kubernetes on premise cluster ingress controller installation error

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am new in kubernetes administration. i just wanted to test ingress controller but i am afraid i get error like below. the pods related to ingress controller wont be running. i searched a lot on internet but didnt find appropriate answer for this case.

**MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "webhook-cert" : secret "ingress-nginx-admission" not found**

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a secret required by your volume. You can read more about secrets here- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/.

It looks like an nginx secret wasn't installed or configured properly. You might be missing a value in your helm chart if that's how it was installed.